# Extract a number from middle of a string to variable

Tags: php

This is the date string I'm working with: `2017-04-18 04:49:06`
I'm writing a script that needs to get the hours to a variable, change it and then replace the new hour value with the old one.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: `date("H", strtotime("2017-04-18 04:49:06"));`

Comment: Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to handle dates in PHP. It allows you to change the components (set date and/or time, add/subtract time intervals) then format it again as string.